# Enabling media streaming from a removable drive using Windows Media Player

Tags: windows-7, streaming, windows-media-player

I have Windows Media Player set up to stream video to several devices in my apartment. I had recently run out of space so I purchased an external drive to store my videos/music etc.

I can add the media to my WMP library and play it locally without issue. As soon as I try to access the media from another device that supports media streaming (Media player or another PC) only the media stored on a fixed drive is available.

**Is there a way to enable media sharing from a removable drive or somehow trick WMP that the media is stored on a fixed drive?**

I tried setting up a [SymLink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) linking a directory on the fixed drive to the removable one but with the same result.

Comment: Have you tried adding the folders on your removable drive to your libraries? WMP works well when streaming libraries. Try it out and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is different than a symlink (I've mainly used Junction Points), but have you tried adding the external drive's partition to windows using a path?  In Computer Management | Disk Management | right click over the partition and select Change Drive Letter and Paths | then choose Add or Change, there you can select Mount in the following empty NTFS folder.

The second option is mount the disk using iSCSI.  Windows has a iSCSI initiator, but I've only used FreeNAS to make an iSCSI target.  When I did this, it looked like a local drive, but I didn't attempt anything with media player library.

I hope one of these work for you.

Comment: Junction Points are specifically the NTFS implementation of a symlink. I would assume mounting the path in an NTFS folder using Disk Management would be identical in execution and result to doing it via CLI.